# How to change fn key function?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Currently, my Fn key toggles mission control. I am looking all through system settings, and I can't find a way to stop the fn key from toggling mission control. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Mission Control system preference

Change the hot key for Mission Control.

By default it is Control up arrow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking in the keyboard settings instead.

Comment: No worries. I went there first to check too, @LionMac